# Display div over canvas in Dojo mobile app

Tags: ios, dojo, html5-canvas

I know this question have been asked many times but I still can't manage to get it to work.

I am developing apps on iPad and generate a globe 3D in WebGL, some of the elements are created with Dojo (like the splitpane).

I basically have a top pane with a canvas and a bottom pane with different stuffs.

```
<div id="splitArea" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.FixedSplitter" data-dojo-props="orientation:'V'">
    <div id="topDiv" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ContentPane">
        <div id="globePane">
            <button class="globeItem" id="metButton" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" onclick="displayOptions('MET')">MET</button>
            <canvas id="globeCanvas"></canvas>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Globe.js"></script>
            <div id="globeOptions"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infosPane" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ContentPane">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the top pane elements CSS :

```
#topDiv {
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%; height: 50%;
}

#globePane {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

#globeCanvas {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#globeOptions {
    width: 150px; height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px; right: 200px;
    z-index: 4;
}

.globeItem {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

And the Javascript that injects globe in the canvas :

```
var container= document.getElementById('globeCanvas');

    if ( Detector.webgl )
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: globeCanvas , antialias:true} );
    else
        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer( { canvas: globeCanvas } );

    renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth,container.offsetHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
    ...
}
```

Now question is : I want a Div (id="globeOptions") to appear on screen when I click a button named "MET", I got at first to create it (what is done in the code), but once created, the div isn't displayed.

The button was created with Dojo and is displayed well on canvas (I didn't do anything special so it must be Dojo auto config that lets it being displayed on canvas), but the div stays under canvas whatever I try.

I tried lots of solutions I found but nothing works (even the relative/absolute positions).

Why does it work on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9JWY2/4/) but doesn't in device, am I doing something wrong?